# I have Bluetooth in Windows 10 but "No Bluetooth Found" in dual-booted Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, bluetooth

Recently, I dual-booted my Windows 10 laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. On Windows I have Bluetooth, moreover it works with my wireless headphone. In Ubuntu I can't turn on Bluetooth and get error "No Bluetooth Found (Put in a dongle to use Bluetooth)". Any suggestions?

Output of "sudo rfkill list":

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```